# String that can be provided to c() that will generate an NA in R

Tags: r

When declaring a character vector, is there any string that R will recognise as NA? i.e. I'm after something that can be put inside `"` and `"` like other strings

I've tried:

`NA_character_` but without `"` and `"`, and this works, but I need it to have the `"` and `"`

```r
c("abc", "def", NA_character_) %>% .[3] %>% is.na
# TRUE
```

When using `"NA_character_"` (i.e. with the `"`)

```r
c("abc", "def", "NA_character_") %>% .[3] %>% is.na
# FALSE
```

Other attempts

```r
c("abc", "def", "NA") %>% .[3] %>% is.na
# FALSE
```

```r
c("abc", "def", "<NA>") %>% .[3] %>% is.na
# FALSE
```

```r
c("abc", "def", "") %>% .[3] %>% is.na
# FALSE
```

I am basically after any word or string that, when wrapped in `"` and `"` in the assignment of a character vector will produce `NA` for just that element of the character vector.

Note: I am open to hacky solutions!

Comment: I am bit unclear on why you are doing this but you can put an empty string (or any string for that matter) and `replace` it with `NA` before evaluating. Something like `c("abc", "def", "") %>% replace(., . == "", NA) %>% is.na` ?

Comment: Can you describe the situation where this is needed? Perhaps there's be a better solution.

Comment: "When declaring a character vector, is there any string that R will recognise as NA?" I really hope (and expect) that there isn't.

Comment: You can wrap any string in `as.numeric` maybe? `c("abc", "def", as.numeric("")) %>% .[3] %>% is.na`? But we need to know the situation as Roman said

Comment: Long story. Basically a script was written in another language (ruby) that generates R code. It works 99% of the time. The ruby code puts strings between `"` and `"`. Due to an oversight, when the code encounters a `nil` value (similar to `NA` in R), it errors. It's hacky, but rather than refactoring the ruby script, if I can find something to substitute for the `nil` values, then that will achieve the same outcome

Comment: So something similar to what Ronak is suggesting, i.e. use `replace` or declare the `nil` as an `na.string` when loading your data

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for you, but you can alter the `is.na` function so that it behaves the exact way you like.

```
is.na.new <- function(x){
  (is.na(x) | x== "NA_character_")
}
```

> is.na.new(c(NA,5,4,"NA_character_"))
>   [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

Apart from this, I haven't heard of any ways to define a new missing value indicator.

Comment: I have been pondering this solution. What if I set NAs to some random string that is highly unlikely to occur (like `l298vunlkjsr23jiKJGKJSh2r8lfkjsdfh`) then include that in the function you recommend (i.e. if x == "l298vunlkjsr23jiKJGKJSh2r8lfkjsdfh" return NA).

Comment: well, it depends on your application, i.e. how large your data will be, how many of these strings you'll needing etc. Having a long string for each NA value can be quite inefficient in terms of memory

Comment: alternatively, you may want to check how `eval(parse(text="NA_character_"))` works